# rDNS / PTR record when using Cloudflare

Tags: email, reverse-dns, cloudflare

I know that Cloudflare, does not support mail trafic and uses dynamic IP's to protect the servers behind it, But I really need to be able to do rDNS lookups on my IP.

I have turned of the Caching and protection for these domains as well, so the receiving server can see my IP, but since it is not able to rDNS lookup my IP it is flagged as SPAM.

Does anyone have a good solution for this, so that I can get the caching and not be flagged as SPAM?

Answer (score 5):

It is a good idea to use different (sub)domains for email and web servers.  For example `mail.example.com` and `www.example.com`  This allows you to resolve this issue fairly easily.

Typically rDNS is typically only required for outgoing SMTP traffic.  You would configure your domain to use the `mail` subdomain as its MX, and configure that domain in the PTR record.

Try checking your domain with `http://iphostinfo.com/cloudflare/` to see other common domains.

Comment: This doesn't help me at all.
I'm not able to create a PTR record, so was wondering what others did to solve this issue when using Cloudflare.

Comment: @Folkman  If you can't get your PTR record created, you will have difficulty sending email to any domain trying to reject SPAM.  In Cloudflare, you need to mark your email servers as direct and loose the DOS protection.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to ask your IP address provider to setup a PTR record for you. Some providers won't do this and will request a DNS server from you. At which point, you'll have to setup your own DNS server (like BIND) to host the PTR record, then ask your provider to delegate lookups to your server.